# cython memory view of c array of structure

Tags: c, arrays, python-2.7, cython

I'm trying to use cython to extract data from some binary files but I'm coming up against a problem and my knowledge of cython/c is not able to solve it.

The problem:
Attempting to make a memoryview of my c array of structures causes a segmentation fault.

What I'm doing:
I have a binary file full of data, the first entry is an unsigned int giving the number of snapshots (Snapshot_Counter) contained in the file.
The next entries are in the format of Snapshot_Information and this block is repeated Snapshot_Counter times.
If I read this in a loop block by block, storing the results in a list it works and I get the right numbers out.

I want to avoid this loop by reading in the array all at once.
I'm trying to extract the Snapshot_Information format information into an array, which I think I have managed to allocate properly. However I can't work out how to see into the array to check if I've got the right data in there. 
I have a feeling it is wrong as the number I'm extracting after this block is wrong.

What I would like to know:
How can I see into this array with a memory view? Am I allocating the memory properly? Is there another way of doing this without a c array?

The code:

```
in extractiontest.pxd

cdef unsigned int Snapshot_Counter

cdef packed struct Snapshot_Information:
     signed int Days
     unsigned int Seconds
     ...more type definitions.


in extractiontest.pyx

rm = fopen("/filepath")

fread(&Snapshot_Counter,4,1,rm) #works fine
cdef Snapshot_Information *snap_info_array = <Snapshot_Information *>malloc(Snapshot_Counter*sizeof(Snapshot_Information))
fread(&snap_info_array, sizeof(Snapshot_Information), Snapshot_Counter, rm)

cdef Snapshot_Information[:] snap_arr_view = <Snapshot_Information[:-1]>snap_info_array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to tell it the length: it can't work out a length from a malloced array:

```
cdef Snapshot_Information[:] snap_arr_view = <Snapshot_Information[:Snapshot_Counter]>snap_info_array
```

I suspect it interprets `-1` as a huge positive integer (hence the segmentation fault)

---

On closer look you also have another bug in your code:

```
fread(<void*>snap_info_array, sizeof(Snapshot_Information), Snapshot_Counter, rm)
```

I've removed the `&` in front of `snap_info_array` and added a cast to `void*` (I'm not sure if you need the cast though). You were telling `fread` to write to the place where the address of your array was kept, rather than into your array.

Comment: Thanks DavidW, I have managed to get it to extract the memoryview, and then using np.asarray(snap_array_view) I can see it is Snapshot_Counter long. Sadly if I try to print any of it, I get a seg fault! So I suspect I've not got to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: @RDavies See edit. I wouldn't like to promise that's the only other issue, but it certainly is an issue

Comment: excellent, that seems to have fixed it. I'm new to the pointers/address thing. Thankyou for your clear explanation.

It does work both with <void *> and nothing in front of the array name.